# How to interpret a non-zero correlation coefficient between 2 sequences of numbers

Tags: self-study, correlation

If I have a sequence of 1000 x_i and y_i values, and they have a correlation coefficient of 0.05. Does this mean that they are guaranteed to not be correlated?

Comment: It means that they are correlated with r = 0.05. No more, no less. Why would you expect some other guarantee?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you plotted your y values against your x values? The Pearson correlation coefficient aims to assess the strength of the *linear* association between x and y. So if it comes out to be really low (i.e., close to zero), your conclusion would be that the *linear* association between x and y is very weak. The plot of y versus x will give you hints as to why the association is so weak.